# Google-api-client-android and google-http-client-android

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I am new in Android. I was trying to make an app using Google place api. All of the tutorial suggest to use api client for android. I downloaded and did everything to use api. I use eclipse and I did what I suggest to do. But there is one problem: I don't know how to use those? What kind of methods they have inside? How to use those methods? Is there any tutorial exist? 
Please help..Thank you all in advance.
It would be more helpful if I get any documentation or something like that for those api like we get different methods details of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Google has official documentation for google-http-java-client in [this link](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Android) and for google-api-java-client in [this link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android).

Both are oriented to Android.

If you want to know more about how to access Google Play Services API, see [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html)

Comment: In 2020, is it still true that we should use google-http-java-client and google-api-java-client for android? Was looking at the Google Play Services API, and am not sure if we should use one of those?